# calculating timeframe accuracy in R

Tags: r, date, analysis, lubridate

I am trying to look at prediction accuracy related to timeframes related to hospital discharge.

For example, I think Mr. Smith will be discharged within 3-7 days, which would mean he could any day from 11/9-11/13 would be correct. If he discharges in 2 days, I would say I was 1 day off and if he discharges within 10 days, I was 3 days off...

Is there any good method to do this using dplyr, base R, and lubridate? TIA. Sample data is at the link:

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLIHw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to express your need in a case_when.

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(DIF = case_when(discharge_calender_date < discharge_prediction_lower_bound ~ discharge_calender_date - discharge_prediction_lower_bound,
                                discharge_calender_date <= discharge_prediction_upper_bound ~ 0,
                                TRUE ~ discharge_calender_date - discharge_prediction_upper_bound))
```

This way you get a negative value if the patient left before the lower bound, zero if he left within the prediction and a positive result if he left after the prediction.

Comment: change "discharge_calender_date" to "discharge_calendar_date" - I have a type there (the names have to match your columns exactly

Comment: works perfectly, thank you for the insights and highlighting `case_when`